# Timing of database operations in ASP.NET page lifecycle

Tags: asp.net, page-lifecycle

According to [the msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx), as you can see on the diagram, a server control's "Data binding events" occurs after all "control changed events". So in the case of a DetailsView control, the ItemInserted event would happen before the database operation? Obviously this cannot be correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the MSDN article for the control's event.

In the case of a [DetailsView.ItemInserted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview.iteminserted.aspx) Event:

> The ItemInserted event is raised when
>   an Insert button within the
>   DetailsView control is clicked, **but
>   after the insert operation**. This
>   allows you to provide an event handler
>   that performs a custom routine, such
>   as checking the results of the insert
>   operation, whenever this event occurs.

There is also the [DetailsView.ItemInserting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview.iteminserting.aspx) Event that is raised *before* the insert to the database